# Infinite card carousel with preview of the previous and next card

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel, infinite-scroll

I am trying to implement a card carousel that shows a small part of the previous and next card. The current card is centered in the middle.

[image: infinite card carousel with preview]

I did some research and found out that `scroll-snap-align` can be used to achieve the results shown in the image above.

HTML:

```
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card">Task 1</div>
  <div class="card">Task 2</div>
  <div class="card">Task 3</div>
  <div class="card">Task 4</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.card-container {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    gap: 16px;
    padding: 16px 0px;
    overflow: scroll;
    scroll-snap-type: both mandatory;
    scroll-padding: 1rem;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    &::-webkit-scrollbar {
        display: none;
    }
}

.card {
    min-height: 240px;
    min-width: 240px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0px 1px 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: 16px;
    scroll-snap-align: center;
}
```

Now I don't know how to implement the infinite scroll. When card 4 is scrolled into the view a preview of card 1 should be shown on the right side of card 4.

This is what it currently looks like:

[image]

This is what I want it to look like:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Addition: I want to solve this without using a library.

Comment: In case you are able to not only include a `min-width` to the cards, but also a fixed `width`: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70469311/8274308) may be what you are looking for, 100% CSS, minor HTML tweaks, no JavaScript.

Comment: No, this solution is jumping back to the beginning. I want it to be seamless.